# Applying scale factor to raster with gdalwarp

Tags: raster, gdalwarp, scale, color

I've been trying to use gdalwarp with the -tr and -te parameters to apply a scale factor to 'stretch' a raster.  The result is a raster with correct extents and pixel size, but no RGB data.  I've also added parameters for -of Gtiff and -ot in various combination to support Byte and Float values.  Color me stuck!

```
gdalwarp $input_raster $scaled_raster -te $scaled_x_ll $scaled_y_ll $scaled_x_ur $scaled_y_ur -tr $scaled_px_x $scaled_px_y -s_srs EPSG:6428 -t_srs EPSG:6428
```

Comment: Do you mean that you want kind of falsify the source data by putting it into another place and pixels stretched? Is the original georeferencing wrong?

Comment: Basically yes.  Georeferencibg is correct in state plane, I am trying to scale to ground based coordinates with a modified state plane approach.  In a second step I truncate the millions to get to friendly coordinates that can be transformed back to grid if needed.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could try is using gdaldem and color-relief option with your own colorscale in a CSV file after you warp the raster. From GDAL docs:

gdaldem color-relief <input_dem> <color_text_file> <output_color_relief_map>
[-alpha] [-exact_color_entry | -nearest_color_entry]
[-b ] [-of format] [-co =]... [-q]

where color_text_file contains lines of the format "elevation_value red green blue"

The elevation_value can actually be whatever scalar value you want.  You just have to provide the color scale file.

There are also a few color options through gdal_translate as well as using the GDAL python script pct2rgb.py.  But I found using gdaldem to be the easiest and straightforward to color an image.

Comment: I am actually trying to scale the pixel size and extents, not the raster value.  Also right now I am focused on an orthophoto.